Laravel + Docker
Я новичок в docker, в ходе изучения статей я пришел к выводу, что есть два одинаковых результата, каким способом докеризируется laravel, так ли это?
1.

создается локальный проект laravel через composer
создаются файлы docker-compose и Dockerfile
создаются различные конф. файлы (nginx, php-fpm, тд.)
запуск команд docker по созданию контейнеров





создаются файлы docker-compose и Dockerfile
создаются различные конф. файлы (nginx, php-fpm, тд.)
запуск команд docker по созданию контейнеров
вход в командную строку контейнера php и создание проекта laravel через composer


Думаю да, различий именно в создании проекта я не вижу. Я использую второй способ - просто чтобы не ставить лишнее (PHP) на комп, и держать все внутри контейнеров. Есть еще dev-контейнеры - еще один способ
